# Create View in MS Access 2007

Tags: ms-access

I have database in MsAccess 2007 having 5 Tables inside them

I want to create View in MS Accesss

I dont need Syntax, but i need Step to create View (because i cant find CreateView in MS Acccess

Answer (score 12):

You cannot create a view in MS Access 2007, it is not supported.  However, you can create a query to return the data that you need.

See [MSDN for Create View Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177895%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

> The Microsoft Access database engine does not support the use of
>   CREATE VIEW, or any of the DDL statements, with non-Microsoft Access
>   database engine databases.

But creating a `SELECT` query is the same as a `View` in that you can retrieve data and use it by other queries.

For example, if you create a query called `GetQuery1` which performs the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
```

If you want to use this like a view, you can call this directly from another query:

```
SELECT *
FROM GetQuery1
```

Comment: How do you give a name to a query? Is this supported via `OleDb` in .NET?

Answer (score 2):

MS Access lets you create a Query which can be used in other Queries. So it is similar to a view

Answer (score -5):

```
CREATE VIEW view [(field1[, field2[, …]])] AS selectstatement
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177895(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: You just copy past it.