# Unable to save query result to variable?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2007

I'm having trouble finding a way to use data from a query in a join, tried a lot of things.

I have the following query:

```
(SELECT COUNT(t1.ticketCount) as ticketCount, Ticket.memberId, Year FROM
(SELECT YEAR(date) as Year, showId, Ticket.memberId FROM
Show, Ticket
WHERE Ticket.show = showId )  as t1
GROUP BY Ticket.memberId, Year)
```

Basically I want to use the data from that query as a table, table1 in a join to do this:

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT Year, MAX(ticketCount) AS MaxTicketCount
FROM table1 GROUP BY Year) groupedtt
ON table1.Year = groupedtt.Year
AND table1.ticketCount = groupedtt.MaxTicketCount
```

**My question: How would I go about using the data from the 1st code section above as a table table1 in the second code section(all in one query)?**

Thanks!

For example the output of the first code segment would be [image]

And the results after the Join would be

[image]

Example of showTable:

[image]

Example of Ticket table:

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you want the _output_ of this query to be? In the outermost `SELECT` list, do you want to get the `Year, MAX(ticketCount)` as the returned columns?  If so, it looks like you _don't_ want the `SELECT Year, MAX(...)` to be in a `FROM` clause subquery.  If not, please post a small sample of the two tables involved and a sample table of what you expect the query output to be.

Comment: I want the output to be the max amount of tickets bought for each year, together with the memberId of the member who bought that amount of tickets that year. So the output would be a memberId together with a year for each year in Year(Show.date)

Comment: Please also post a sample of the `Show` table.

Comment: OK, posted along with a sample of ticket. (I only use showId to get the correct year for each show)

Comment: As an additional note, I can easily get the max count grouped with each year, but I can't also select memberId, because then access forces me to group by memberId, and that brings all the other non max values back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem now by making two different querys and doing a select from those two as tables. As shown by the answer here:
[Create View in MS Access 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367959/create-view-in-ms-access-2007)