# ACCESS keeping giving me a syntax error, when trying to create a view

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

```
CREATE VIEW TopLevelCrust AS
    SELECT CustomerName, Street, City, State, Balance, CreditLimit
    FROM Customer
    Where CreditLimit >= 10000;
```

When I attempt to run the command, it gives me an error message. And highlights `"VIEW"`, I cannot tell what it wants me to change, suggestions.

Comment: ...what is the rest of the error message?

Comment: syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: that the only message I'm getting

Comment: i'm not an access dev but doesn't look like they have views.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367959/create-view-in-ms-access-2007  but you didn't say which version you were using.

Comment: Microsoft access 2016, thanks i did check it out and its for access 2007 which doesn't support views

Comment: do you need to define the columns in the view?
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CREATE-VIEW-Statement-ffcd67a0-047f-448d-a069-24c8f3e165ba

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attempting CREATE VIEW in Access gives "Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770318/attempting-create-view-in-access-gives-syntax-error-in-create-table-statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view is just a saved select query. `create view` is not supported in Access.

Create the following query in design view/ sql view:

```
SELECT CustomerName, Street, City, State, Balance, CreditLimit
FROM Customer
Where CreditLimit >= 10000;
```

and save it as `TopLevelCrust`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use ADO - I assume you're trying to run this command through a DAO connection. That's not possible.

Change your connection to an ADO/OLEDB connection and redo the statement.

More details at [Attempting CREATE VIEW in Access gives "Syntax error in CREATE TABLE statement"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32770318/attempting-create-view-in-access-gives-syntax-error-in-create-table-statement)